# Set interval color surface with plt.clim on 3d projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I have some data, for example:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(20, 50, 30)
z = np.linspace(-10, 5, 15)
data = np.random.rand(10,30,15)
```

where all of the elements from the data have .2f decimals and the difference between the max and  the min of the data are small, so I need to set an inverval to get the contrast of the data values. I will visualize the data to surfacecolor. I tried this but unfortunately it did not work:

```
ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111,projection ='3d')

for i in range(len(x)):
    surfcol = plt.cm.jet(data[i])
    ax.plot_surface(x[i][:,0:len(data[i])],
                    y[i][:,0:len(data[i])],
                    z[i][:,0:len(data[i])],
                    facecolors=surfcol)
plt.clim(-0.01,0.01)
plt.show()
```

when I try using `pcolormesh` on 2d projection, it does work. The code looks like this:

```
plt.pcolormesh(data)
plt.clim(-0.01,0.01)
plt.show()
```

I am using `plt.clim` to look at the contrast of the data values.
I have trouble with `plt.clim()` where I want to visualize a 3d projection, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The color in the pcolormesh is determined via a colormap and normalization, which can then be manipulated via `clim`. In the `plot_surface` case, you set the individual colors manually via the `facecolors`, so `clim` has no effect. Instead, you need to supply the actual colors you would like to see.

Comment: should i use `matplotlib.cm` to set colors manually? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Yes, you can use the colormaps to generate the colors you like.